# menuconfig! failed

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install drivers and when I try to run the command make menuconfig I get the error message that the "display is too small " "It must be at least 19 lines by 80 columns." And the terminal size is
[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you tell us more about which driver you are installing and possibly link us to the relevant make file you are using?

Comment: You can check if it's so indeed with `perl -e 'foreach (1..19) {print "x" x 80 . "\n"}'`.

Comment: That's the _initial_ terminal size, not necessarily the _current_ terminal size.