# sudo make menuconfig error

Tags: linux, kernel

[image]

It says "Your display is too small to run Menuconfig.It must be at least 19 lines by 80 columns" but the terminal size is 80x24. How do I solve this?

Comment: What does `echo $COLUMNS $LINES` output?

Comment: I imagine this is the same question as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/547490/86440), is that right?